# Is there possibility to restrict an image within kineticJS Group boundary itself?

Tags: html, kineticjs

Is there possibility to restrict an image within kineticJS Group boundary itself?

I am adding an image to the kineticJS Group, where the group has width and height. I need to restrict tha added t image within that Group boundary itself. Is this possible? As well I resize that added image small or bigger one ( i.e. Image size won't go bigger than Group height and width).

Is this possible to restrict that image within that Group boundary itself.

Comment: Yes, investigate the `dragBoundFunc` to limit a dragged image to its containing group.

Comment: but when resize image within that group that dragBoundFunc function not working properly.

Comment: You don't provide code to show how you're resizing so I can't answer specifically, but in general you would calc if the bounding box of the resized image would extend beyond the group bounding box. The 4 sides of a bounding box are Left=x, Top=y, Right=x+width, Height=y+height.  You also don't mention what you want to occur if the images exceeds the group boundary, but I guess you could downsize the image to fit within the group boundary when you discover it has exceeded that boundary.